# Does pdf.js cache PDF files?

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, webview, pdf.js

I am trying to integrate pdf.js into an Javafx Application. I use the sample viewer.html from https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/. So I load the viewer.html with an empty file parameter (so no page is rendered at first) in a WebView. Then I run PDFViewerApplication.open from Code. Doing this the wanted PDF is rendered fine. Now if I change something in the PDF and run PDFViewerApplication.open the Viewer reloads but shows the old version of the PDF again.

A minimal example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
        Button btn = new Button("load");
        btn.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("PDFViewerApplication.open(\"" + new File("latex/invoice.pdf").toURI().toURL().toString() + "\");");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        webView.getEngine().load(new File("js/web/viewer.html").toURI().toURL().toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

There are 2 problems which I suspect could happen:

1. There is a problem with CORS which is highly unlikely because the PDF is loaded once
2. The pdf file is cached in any way in pdf.js

Because I suspect problem 2 is more likely my questions are:
Does pdf.js cache PDF files and if it does how can I make it stop caching files? If it does noch cache PDF files what else could be the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I make it stop caching files?

The question is old, but I am adding an answer as I got the same issue recently, and to stop caching files I just added a random string after the pdf URL, like:

```
{url}/100207300003.pdf?v678281
```

This resolved the issue with the same file loading again and again.

Comment: it's not working for me!

Comment: @Criss How are you doing it? Create a new question and describe your problem in detail there...

Answer (score 0):

You say you are changing PDF content, but its not clear how the PDF editor is used to save changes to the Fully open file.

Editing needs the full file cached in order to calculate the internal file lengths between PDF objects if they are added or removed.

Naturally we can add annotation in a browser and the full length of the cache with changes at the end can then be written as a new filename.

Then the cache can be closed so as to open using the new filename. Opening the old filename will not include any change.